How do I enable a custom user role to assign categories to a custom post type in Wordpress?
I've made a custom user role and gave it only permissions to edit, publish, delete and read the custom post type and categories. They are able to change a category, but can't assign them to the posts. However an admin user can assign categories to the posts in the custom post type.
What could be blocking a specific userrole to assign categories to this custom post type?
I've installed two plugins to check and edit the permissions of the userroles but to no effect. Even creating a complete new user role and assigning the right permissions doesn't work.
The second option I tried is copying all data in the option_value cell of the wp_options table of the database. I've counted the permissions of the admin and custom user role but these are both 15.
Inspect element shows me that the input fields are disabled.

Please post the code for the custom role. Also, just a reminder, if you are following the directions for properly registering the role, and you change the role’s capabilities, you need to re-register it
